# How do I hide the console after starting a Windows application from it?

Tags: c, windows

I have an app that opens the console and then it opens the GUI, but the console does not disappear.

Is there any way of hiding the console window?

Thanks

Comment: Hiding the console is not something C will do for you. That will depend on the display system you're using.

Comment: what system/framework are you builing on?

Comment: I think that what you're looking for is a daemon process ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computing%29). Maybe a duplicate of this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384168/how-to-make-a-process-daemon

Comment: Don't compile it as a console executable: [How to have an executable file run without a console?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29882262/how-to-have-an-executable-file-run-without-a-console)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include <windows.h>

int main(void) {

    printf("%s", "Hello from the console.\n");

    MessageBox(NULL, "Click OK to hide the console.", "", MB_ICONINFORMATION);

    ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE);

    MessageBox(NULL, "Console is now hidden.", "", MB_ICONINFORMATION);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you really don't want the console window at all, instead call [`FreeConsole`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683150).

Comment: Should that not be `<windows.h>`?

Comment: @Simon possible, tbh I don't understand the rule. Could you explain why should this be `<windows.h>`?

Comment: You would use `include<windows.h>` when `windows.h` is in your library (the standard one).  You would use `#include "windows.h"` when `windows.h` is along with your c file (or in a sub dictionary in which case it would be `#include"sub_file/windows.h"`.

Comment: I thought the `windows.h` header is always part of the standard library.  In which case it should be `<windows.h>`